# Retrieving data that contains nested arrays in Reactive Forms (FormArray)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm having trouble retrieving data with nested arrays and then displaying it in my Reactive Form (the data in the second level array gets duplicated). The problem seems to be the way I am looping the data but I'm not sure what to do to fix it. To clarify I have an example below (the problem emerges with the array2 property).

**Original Data Object**

```
nestedData = {
nestOne: "Level One",
array1: [
  {
    nestTwo: "A",
    array2: ["Tag A"]
  },
  {
    nestTwo: "B",
    array2: ["Tag B"]
  }
]};
```

**Below is the Reactive Code**

```
 nestedForm: FormGroup;
 let array_one = new FormArray([]);
 let array_two = new FormArray([]);
 // If an If block to check if 'array1' property is present;
 if (this.nestedData['array1']) {
    for (let ar1 of this.nestedData.array1) {
    // IF BLOCK FOR array2
        if (ar1['array2']) {
        // For loop to get array2 data
            for (let ar2 of ar1.array2) {

                array_two.push(
                    new FormControl(ar2, Validators.required),
                )

            }
        } //IF Block Ends

        array_one.push(
            new FormGroup({
                'nestTwo': new FormControl(ar1.nestTwo),
                'array2': array_two
            })
        );
    }
}

this.nestedForm = this.fb.group({
    'nestedOne': [this.nestedData.nestOne],
    'array1': array_one
});
```

**Now this is the outcome when looking at:**

```
{{nestedForm.value | json}}
```

```
    {
    "nestedOne": "Level One",
    "array1": [
        {
            "nestTwo": "A",
            "array2": [
                "Tag A",
                "Tag B"
            ]
        },
        {
            "nestTwo": "B",
            "array2": [
                "Tag A",
                "Tag B"
            ]
        }

}
```

As you can see. Tag A and Tag B appears in both array2 properties when it should not. I don't know the best way to retrieve array2 data and then push it into the Reactive FormArray while also keeping it containing within its parent array1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the second form array inside the **for** loop just before **if** statement. By doing so, you are making sure that you will not be pushing the **array2** values into the same form.

```
nestedForm: FormGroup;
let array_one = new FormArray([]);
// If an If block to check if 'array1' property is present;
if (this.nestedData['array1']) {
    for (let ar1 of this.nestedData.array1) {
     let array_two = new FormArray([]); // initialize here
     // IF BLOCK FOR array2
        if (ar1['array2']) {
        // For loop to get array2 data
         for (let ar2 of ar1.array2) {
             array_two.push(new FormControl(ar2, Validators.required));
         }
    } //IF Block Ends

    array_one.push(
        new FormGroup({
            'nestTwo': new FormControl(ar1.nestTwo),
            'array2': array_two // but if the data is not available, you will be pushing empty form array here
        })
    );
  }
}

this.nestedForm = this.fb.group({
    'nestedOne': [this.nestedData.nestOne],
    'array1': array_one
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I have been struggling with this issue for awhile now and never realized that the problem was where in the code I was putting my array_two variable.

Comment: I am glad that it worked for you. Could you accept my answer now..lol